# What is the advantage of Borel sigma algebras in defining probability spaces?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I'm trying to get the central concepts correct, so I'm going to express them without embellishment.

1. A Borel $\sigma$ algebra is defined as a sigma algebra generated by a topological space
       $(M,\mathcal{T})$. If $M$ is $\mathbb{R}$, it will typically
       be the "standard topology" defined as the set of all open intervals.
2. Because a $\sigma$ algebra is closed under intersection of infinitely-countably many sub-sets, we can prove that $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n\geq1}(a -\frac{1}{n},\,b)= [a,b)$. This step would not be possible within the topological space where only finite intersections are allowed. So we "recover" closed and half-closed intervals, thanks to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.
3. Now, the half-open intervals are in the sigma algebra (and so are closed intervals), and can be assigned a measure.

So we went through quite a bit of maneuvering (assuming all this is correct) for what purpose? In particular, if we focus on probability spaces, the probability of a close interval is the same as an open interval, since the probability of any point in the real line is zero.

Here is a tentative, unsophisticated, and crass way of looking at it (I'm posting it here to get further feedback):

We can't assign a probability measure to $[0,1]$ because of Cantor's different types of infinites, and $2^Ω$ of $[0,1]$ being far too big, etc. But we want a smooth domain, so that we can get a nice $pdf$ to integrate over... Solution: start with the standard topology over the real line, and then "fill" the gaps by turning it into a sigma algebra.

Reference: On minute:sec 57:39 of [this video](https://youtu.be/6ad9V8gvyBQ?t=57m53s) the speaker ends up the segment with the words: "That very often is very useful." This prompted my question. Where is it needed in probability?

Comment: There are a lot more sets than just intervals and they can get a bit bizarre, e.g. the Cantor set.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the Cantor set, but I'm just scratching the surface of measure theory and topology, and I'm looking for a motivating statement to justify the "trouble" of these mathematical "acrobatics" in the context of probability spaces.

Comment: The reason we go through the trouble is that many spaces of interest (in practice) come equipped with a nice topology. The open sets tell us a lot about continuity, so we want to use those to develop the measure space (so that continuous functions are naturally packaged into the theory - we like to integrate continuous functions!). The basic axioms of measure theory tacked on to the topological space is what causes the issues and makes measure theory very complicated in some ways.

Comment: So could you draw the tentative conclusion: "We can't assign a probability measure to [0,1] because of Cantor's different types of infinites, and $2^\Omega$ of [0,1] is far too big, etc. But we want a smooth domain, so that we can get a nice pdf to integrate over... Solution: start with the standard topology over the real line, and then "fill" the gaps by turning it into a sigma algebra. Is that it?

Comment: I think that's a good way of thinking about it, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very good question. The answer is not so simple, but I would say that there are two main reasons why we like a lot Borel measures on the line (or preferably their Lebesgue counterpart):

- they are regular, which is a wonderful property to establish many properties of the measures, such as when dealing with the relation with topological properties;
- they allow defining conditional measures, which is an important concept in further developments of probability theory, such as stochastic processes.

It should be emphasized that both properties (somehow respectively of semilocal and local nature) fail in general for arbitrary Borel measures on arbitrary metrizable spaces.

There other also less simple reasons why we like measures of the type that you mention. These include stisfying a Lebesgue differentiation theorem (not only for the Lebesgue measure, but for the completion of any Borel measure on the line) and in fact being all that is needed to consider Borel measures on $\mathbb R^n$ (which turn out to be superfluous). But this would be a long story.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please comment on my added appendix to the OP?

Comment: Your description is really not a good way of looking at measure theory in general, although it is a good starting point for the beginning of the theory. In further developments the canon is completely different from what you describe (say for ergodic theory, even for smooth ergodic theory), the reason being that many of the natural structures are rarely smooth or even continuous!

Comment: Incidentally, "regularity" (see my answer) is the ultimate property leading to your comments on open/closed sets and their generalizations.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Would it be possible to break apart my comment at the end of the OP for whatever truth it may contain, and also for its clear shortcomings?

Comment: Well, we certainly don't need a "smooth domain" neither "a nice pdf to integrate", so indeed, it is not quite appropriate to say that we want these. :)

Answer (score 2):

Defining a measure is defining a rule to measure things. The first thing you do in order to do that is to decide *what* sets you want to measure: picking a sigma-algebra is precisely the act of deciding what sets you will measure.

Now picking the Borel sigma-algebra is *exactly* saying that you will measure open sets.

There are no acrobatics involved...

Comment: "Acrobatics" wasn't meant to elicit controversy, just emphasize the issue in the question. That being said, it just seems as though not happy with open sets, we end up closing them, thanks to the fact that within a sigma algebra we can perform unlimited number of intersections (as opposed to a topology). So what is the motivation behind this?

Comment: Well, if you intend to measure a set you automatically measure it's complement.

Comment: As for countable unions, well, experience tells us that we also want that. If you wait a bit, you will see how useful it is to have that available.

Comment: Can I conclude that if we didn't make sure to include closed and half-closed sets, we wouldn't be able to get the probability of the complement?

Comment: The sets you put in the sigma-algebra are those that you will measure. If you want to measure the open sets, in one hand, and, on the other if you want to be able to measure the complement of every set you want to measure, then you of course need to include the closed sets in the sigma-algebra, for the closed sets are precisely the complements of the open sets!

Comment: OK. It makes sense... So this is the motivation behind resorting to the topology to then turn it into a Borel sigma algebra? If it is that simple, I'll be delighted! Yet, again, the intervals in pdf's have the same probability whether the endpoints are included or excluded...

Comment: The motivation is simply that you want to measure open sets.

Comment: Once you accept that, the rest is just technical details. I suggest you try not to over think about them.

Comment: If you have $X \sim N(0,1)$ - a standard normal, and you want the probability of being between $(0,0.4)$, you are asking the same as the probability of getting a result from $[0,0.4]$. So (I know how naive the question is), why not just be happy with open sets? The complementary could be $(-\infty, 0) +  (0.4, \infty)$ avoiding $0.4$ and $0$.

Comment: s I said, there are technical reasons why you want the class of sets you want to measure to be closed under intersections and countable unions. **That** is why you are not just happy with the open sets. I **really** think the best for you is to keep that slogan: «I want to measure open sets, the need for the rest is technical and I will appreciate it later when I know more measure theory»

Comment: The definitions are what they are because people were led to make them in that way in order to be able to prove theorems. But what they wanted, really, was to measure open sets.